# Shilov Linear Algebra Ch 4 Question 9

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am stuck at this question from Shilov's Linear Algebra Chapter 4. Is the linear space in question really a linear space? It seems not.

a. Given $x \in \mathbf K_n^m$ and $y \in \mathbf K_n^m$, $x + y \in \mathbf K_n^m$ is also a linear operator.

b. Given $x \in \mathbf K_n^m$ and $\lambda \in K_n^m$, $\lambda x$ does not make sense since both of them maps from $\mathbf K_n$ into $\mathbf K_m$.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Scalar $\lambda$ should be in $\mathbf K$, not $\mathbf{K_n^m}$; and did you mean $x+y$ is also a linear *operator*?

Comment: Why do you denote linear maps by $\;x,y\;$ ? That may be confusing. If you want to check whether $\;K_n^m\;$ is a linear space you must first define operations on it. THese are sum: $\;f,g\in K_n^m\implies (f+g)(x):=f(x)g(x),\,\,x\in K_n\;,\;\;(\lambda f)(x):=\lambda f(x)\,,\,\,\lambda\in K\;$ . With these operations, $\;K_n^m\;$ becomes a $\;K\,-$ linear space of dimension $\;nm\;$ .If you are clear up to here then you try to continue

Comment: Thanks for comments. But the question is asking linear space of linear operators, so the field is set of linear operators, right?

Comment: No, the field is $\;K\;$, the same over which the linear (vector) spaces themselves, $\;K_n,\,K_m\;$ are defined.

Comment: J. W. Tanner Yes, a typo

Comment: DonAntonio Ok, it seems I have misunderstood the question. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1):

$K_n$ and $K_m$ are vector spaces over the field $K$. The subscripts refer to the dimensions. $K_n$ is not necessarily the vector space $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):x_1,\ldots,x_n\in K\}$, although the latter is an obvious example of $K_n$.

$K_n^m$ is a function space. Every member $L\in K_n^m$ is a linear function. By definition,
$$
K_n^m=\{L:K_n\to K_m\mid L \text{ is a $K$-linear map}\}.
$$
The notation $K_n^m$ doesn't mean $(K_n)^m$ or $(K^m)_n$. The subscript $n$ and the superscript $m$ simply denote the dimensions of the domain and codomain of $L$.

$K_n^m$ is a vector space over the field $K$. The "vectors" in this vector space are linear maps from $K_n$ to $K_m$. When $\lambda,\mu\in K$ and $L_1,L_2$ are linear maps from $K_n$ to $K_m$, the linear combination $L=\lambda L_1+\mu L_2$ means the function defined by
$$
L(x)=\lambda\left(L_1(x)\right)+\mu\left(L_2(x)\right)
$$
for all $x\in K_n$. (Note that $L_1(x)$, the image of $x$ under $L_1$, is a vector in $K_m$. Hence $\lambda\left(L_1(x)\right)$ is a scalar multiplication in $K_m$. The addition $\lambda\left(L_1(x)\right)+\mu\left(L_2(x)\right)$ also takes place in $K_m$.) Since $L_1$ and $L_2$ are linear, it can be proved that $L$ is linear as well.